# How to configure ports for multiple peers in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm having an issue with configuring ports for multiple peers in Hyperledger Fabric (50+) where my existing configuring doesn't seem to work. Below is the sample config for 5 peers in Organization 1 and the rest of the config follows the same logic. Please take a look at it and suggest what I should read/do to fix this. I'm a beginner and would love some feedbacks. Thank you.

```
`networks:   test:
    external:
      name: test

services:   ordererexamplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == manager
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.3
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - ordererexamplecom:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - orderer.example.com

  orderer2examplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == worker1
    container_name: orderer2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.3
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - orderer2examplecom:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 8050:7050
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - orderer2.example.com

  orderer3examplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == worker2
    container_name: orderer3.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.3
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - orderer3examplecom:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 9050:7050
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - orderer3.example.com

  orderer4examplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == worker3
    container_name: orderer4.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.3
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - orderer4examplecom:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 10050:7050
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - orderer4.example.com

  orderer5examplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == worker4
    container_name: orderer5.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.3
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - orderer5examplecom:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 11050:7050
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - orderer5.example.com

  peer0org1examplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == manager
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.3
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=test
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=false
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0org1examplecom:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - peer0.org1.example.com

  peer1org1examplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == manager
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.3
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=test
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variables
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7061
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7061
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7071
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7071
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7061
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:7061
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=false
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer1org1examplecom:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7061:7061
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - peer1.org1.example.com

  peer2org1examplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == manager
    container_name: peer2.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.3
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=test
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer2.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer2.org1.example.com:7062
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7062
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer2.org1.example.com:7072
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7072
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer2.org1.example.com:7062
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer2.org1.example.com:7062
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=false
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer2org1examplecom:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7062:7062
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - peer2.org1.example.com

  peer3org1examplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == manager
    container_name: peer3.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.3
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=test
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer3.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer3.org1.example.com:7063
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7063
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer3.org1.example.com:7073
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7073
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer3.org1.example.com:7063
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer3.org1.example.com:7063
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=false
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer3.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer3.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer3org1examplecom:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7063:7063
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - peer3.org1.example.com

  peer4org1examplecom:
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == manager
    container_name: peer4.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.3
    environment:
      #Generic peer variables
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=test
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      # Peer specific variabes
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer4.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer4.org1.example.com:7064
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7064
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer4.org1.example.com:7074
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7074
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer4.org1.example.com:7064
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer4.org1.example.com:7064
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=false
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer4.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - /home/ubuntu/hlf-docker-swarm/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer4.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer4org1examplecom:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7064:7064
    networks:
      test:
        aliases:
          - peer4.org1.example.com `
```

I did manage to deploy 50 peer nodes in 5 different machines on AWS for testing; however, I see that peers occupy the same port of peer0 for each organization (Ex: 7051 for all 10 peers in organization 1). I'm not sure what I have been doing wrong as I can't find any resource on port configuration. Is it fine to deploy multiple peers at once or do I have to deploy one peer per org and add them later? Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a repository to show how do you need to change aaaall the configuration and the scripts in order to run something more complex than the basic example 2 peers (admin) - 2 orgs.

https://github.com/rastafaninplakeibol/HyperledgerFabric8peers2Orgs

Here you'll see how I managed to deploy a network made of 8 peers (1 admin and 3 peers for each org) - 2 orgs. Once you get started it is easy to add how many peers you need, you just need to follow the flow of the different scripts and change them according to your plans.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, sorry for late reply. I have checked your repo and config files. It seems like I follow the same logic as yours. However, my network doesn't seem to run properly. I can see my peers use the same 7051 port across all orgs and I can't deploy more than 10 peers per one organization. I have no idea why this is happening since I configure all the necessary config files like configtx.yaml, docker-compose-test-net, docker-compose-couch, docker-compose-ca, and more.

Comment: I have tried my own configuration and yours, and I always face the same error:

all peer 0 of any org I have tried will start just fine (peer 0 org 1, peer 0 org 2, peer 0 org 3 and so on), but starting from peer 1 and peer 2 up until peer 20 for example, they all exit with the same error: "0001 ERRO [main] InitCmd -> Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, specified path "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp" does not exist or cannot be accessed: stat /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: no such file or directory".

I suppose your config runs fine on your machine, but why is it like this with mine?